# CodeIgniter process multi input fields added with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, input

I have a form adding data into db. I have single input field and button which add more input fields on click. My question is how to grab in controller all inputs and send it to model. My code so far is:
jQuery:

```
<script>
    $('a').click(function(e){
        
        
       $('#inp').append('<div><input class = "new_input" type=text name="name[]"/><a class="remove_field "href="#"> X</a><div><br/>');
       $('.remove_field').click( function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         $(this).parent('div').remove();
       })
    });
</script>
```

form:

```
<?php
// Forma za unos podataka
echo  $this->session->flashdata('item');
echo '<h4>Unesite podatke</h4>';
echo '<div id="warning"></div>';

$att = array('name'=>'form','onsubmit'=>" return validation()");
echo form_open('admin/crud/adding/',$att);

echo form_label('Novi podatak:', 'input_data_info') . br() . br();
$data = array(
              'name'        => 'input_data_info',
              'id'          => 'input_data_info',
              'placeholder'       => 'Unestite podatke',
             );

echo form_input($data) . br() . br();
echo '<div id="inp"></div>';

echo "<a href='#'>".'Novi unos'."</a>" .br() .br();
echo form_submit('save', 'Snimi') . br() . br();
echo form_submit('add', 'Dodaj').br();


echo form_close();

?>
```

controller:

```
$input_data_info = (string)$this->input->post('input_data_info', TRUE);
             //model za dodavanje podataka 
            $this->load->model('Data');
            $query = $this->Data->add($input_data_info);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first input field name is 'input_data_info' and then JQuery adds input fields with 'name[ ]'

As you want to pull the data from all the input fields, they , first need to have a common name.

So, rename the input field that you have created initially in the form to name= 'name[]' that makes your code:

```
$data = array(
          'name'        => 'name[]',
          'id'          => 'input_data_info',
          'placeholder'       => 'Unestite podatke',
         );
```

Then in you controller use something like this:

$all_input_data = $this->input->post('name');

//the $all_input_data is an array containing all your input values.

Comment: if you get confused about the post your controller is receiving, you can just use echo "<pre>"; print_r($all_input_data); This shows you all the array content in an organized fashion!!